# Stop cube rotation on mouse hover

Tags: html, hover, cube

I somehow manage to create this. I created a cube, that rotate horizontally, when it is hovered, but i want it to stay at its current location when it is not hovered. Ive been searching this for awhile now, but I cant seem to find the answer.

```
<html>
<style>
    .wrap {
        -moz-perspective: 800px;
        -webkit-perspective: 800px;
        perspective: 800px;
        -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
        -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
        perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
    }

    .cube {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .cube div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .back {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
        background: orange;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .right {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
        -moz-transform-origin: top right;
        background: yellow;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .left {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
        -moz-transform-origin: center left;
        background: violet;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .top {
        -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
        -moz-transform-origin: top center;
        background: green;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .bottom {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
        -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
        background: blue;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .front {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(100px);
        background: red;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); }
    }

    .cube:hover {
        animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
        -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="cube">
            <div class="front">front</div>
            <div class="back">back</div>
            <div class="top">top</div>
            <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
            <div class="left">left</div>
            <div class="right">right</div>
        </div>
    </div
</body>
</html>
```

Anynone can point me to the right direction? thank you very much,

Comment: `<head>` tag is missing and the `<style>` tag should be wrapped inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor missing `<head>...</head>` tags is valid, both start and end tags for `head` element are optional (unless it's XHTML). It's worse that doctype is missing (so the page will be rendered in Quirks mode) and there is no `title`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the animation for all states of `.cube`, and just toggle `animation-play-state` on hovering (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AXAeG/)):

```
   .cube {
        /* other styles... */
        -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
        animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }

    /* other rules... */

    .cube:hover {        
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
        animation-play-state: running;
    }
```

Also, I suppose that now there is no much need to specify `-moz`-properties for transforms and animations because Firefox supports them unprefixed since version 16 (it's 7 versions back!).

Answer (score 0):

Following CSS will call in case of `mouse hover`, as there is no spinning animation within this, it won't trigger any animation

```
.cube : hover {
   //Do nothing
   }
```